# gripe with the syntax of `CHECK`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue with the syntax of `CHECK`, particularly the way it is meant to appear alongside a column. An example to make this concrete:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION greater_than_10(x INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
'SELECT $1>10;'
LANGUAGE SQL; 

CREATE TABLE A (
    v1 INTEGER CHECK (greater_than_10(v1)),
    v2 INTEGER CHECK (greater_than_10(v2))
)
```

Here's my issue: why does the `CHECK` have to appear alongside a column? If it was only meant to appear alongside a column, then passing the parameter is superfluous since, that value of that column should be implicit. However the below syntax is equally correct:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    v1 INTEGER CHECK (greater_than_10(v2)),
    v2 INTEGER CHECK (greater_than_10(v1))
)
```

which demonstrates that the `CHECK` is not bound to the specific column, but rather to the entire row and can use values from other rows as well as in the following example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_more_than_10(x INTEGER, y INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
'SELECT $1+$2>10;'
LANGUAGE SQL;         

CREATE TABLE A (
    v1 INTEGER CHECK (sum_more_than_10(v1, v2)),
    v2 INTEGER 
)
```

In this last case whether the `CHECK` appears on column `v1` or in column `v2` makes no difference. So why is the `CHECK` bound, syntactically, to a column? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in a CHECK constraint doesn't have to be a single-argument function call.  Instead of calling your `greater_than_10` function, you could just write `CHECK (v1 > 10)`.  Or you could write `CHECK (20 < (v1 * 2))`.  The column name can appear anywhere in the expression; it's not implied to be in any particular place.

Also, column constraints are really just syntactic sugar for table constraints.  When you write

```
v1 INTEGER CHECK (v1 > 10),
v2 INTEGER CHECK (v2 > 10)
```

it's equivalent to writing

```
v1 INTEGER,
v2 INTEGER,
CHECK (v1 > 10),
CHECK (v2 > 10)
```

You can even combine both into one constraint:

```
v1 INTEGER,
v2 INTEGER,
CHECK ((v1 > 10) AND (v2 > 10))
```

Comment: that's exactly what I am saying in the examples I am giving. Isn't it then a poor choice of syntax to allow CHECK to appear alongside a column when in fact it applies to the whole row? And moreover to not make the column name implicit when the CHECK does in fact appear next to a column (suggesting that the developer is hinting that the CHECK only uses this column's value?)

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: that's how the SQL standard defines the syntax.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus, the column name can't be implicit because you have to write a valid Boolean expression.  How would you write something like `CHECK (name = lower(name))` without mentioning `name`?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus, for most column constraints, the column name *is* implicit, and it lets you write your constraints more concisely:  for example, `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` is simpler than `id SERIAL, PRIMARY KEY (id)`.  For a CHECK constraint you don't get that benefit from writing it as a column constraint, but that's no reason for SQL to *forbid* doing so.